# billingClient.queryPurchases returns the list with already cancelled subsription

Tags: android, google-play, play-billing-library

Steps to reproduce (test account):

1. Complete subscription process in the app
2. Cancel subscription in Play Store app and wait till it ends to completion (for monthly test subscriptions 5 minutes for the date of writing)

**Expected:** Subscription is no longer in the list which billingClient.**queryPurchases**(SUB_SKU_TYPE) returns

**Actual:** Subscription is still in the list which billingClient.**queryPurchases**(SUB_SKU_TYPE) returns (even after ~1 hour)

Reported bug: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/122

As it is stated in the documentation **queryPurchases** works with cache without doing any network calls, this could be a reason for this issue. **queryPurchaseHistoryAsync** could be a good alternative but Purchase class doesn't have state of the actual purchase (i.e. SUBSCRIBED, CANCELLED, etc.).

Is there any option to fix this issue using Play Billing Lib or it is required to make direct network calls using old In-App Billing Api?

Comment: That's exactly the thing I am currently working on. The documentation sais "queryPurchaseHistoryAsync() returns the most recent purchase made by the user for each SKU, even if that purchase is expired, canceled, or consumed. Use the queryPurchases() method whenever possible as it uses the local cache, in preference to the queryPurchaseHistoryAsync() method."- so according to that, the method returns all the purchases (doesn't matter if expired or not)...

Comment: Any progress? Facing the same thing. How am I supposed to check if a user is subscribed?

Comment: It seems that there are no progress yet: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73982566